# Plotting two date histograms with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two datetime series, which I'm trying to plot side by side with a shared X-axis.

```
dates1 = ['2015-02-02', '2016-06-29', '2016-06-01', '2015-07-19', '2016-08-17', '2016-11-22',
'2016-07-24', '2016-10-30', '2015-02-01', '2017-01-29', '2015-03-19', '2016-09-06',
'2016-11-23', '2016-06-21', '2016-10-05', '2016-02-23', '2016-11-24', '2016-10-05',
'2015-07-16', '2016-06-07', '2016-07-31', '2016-11-01', '2016-11-02', '2016-08-16',
'2015-06-09', '2016-04-11', '2017-02-09', '2015-05-20', '2016-05-17', '2016-09-12',
'2015-08-05', '2017-02-19']

dates2 = ['2016-03-22', '2016-03-16', '2015-07-02', '2016-09-13', '2014-09-04', '2016-07-12',
'2016-05-08', '2016-02-18', '2014-07-10', '2016-05-10', '2016-05-02', '2016-11-20',
'2015-05-19', '2016-01-06', '2016-06-21', '2015-03-25', '2016-06-09', '2016-12-07',
'2016-10-18', '2016-03-27', '2017-03-19', '2016-10-27', '2017-01-12', '2015-12-31',
'2016-05-05', '2016-07-17', '2016-07-10', '2017-06-14', '2015-12-27', '2016-03-01', 
'2016-05-04', '2017-05-15']

ser1 = pd.Series(dates1, dtype=np.datetime64)
ser2 = pd.Series(dates2, dtype=np.datetime64)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(20, 10), sharex=True)
ser1.groupby([ser1.dt.year, ser1.dt.month]).count().plot(kind='bar', ax=axes[0])
ser2.groupby([ser2.dt.year, ser2.dt.month]).count().plot(kind='bar', ax=axes[1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

As seen in the image, it appears that `ser1` has `(2014, 7)` values, but its first actual value is `2015-02-01`. For reference, the two plots with `sharex=False`:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(20, 10), sharex=False)
ser1.groupby([ser1.dt.year, ser1.dt.month]).count().plot(kind='bar', ax=axes[0])
ser2.groupby([ser2.dt.year, ser2.dt.month]).count().plot(kind='bar', ax=axes[1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Any simple way to solve this, without manually limiting the X-axis?

Comment: Aside from my answer, this seems to be a bug in either matplotlib or pandas. The two graphs seem to share the same ticks (integer numbers which are not seen), but not the tick labels, and this causes incorrect data to appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate the `ser1` and `ser2` groupby count results, which will cause rows of NaNs to appear in missing dates of both series. Then simply `fillna` with zeros and proceed with the same plot method:

```
sgp1 = ser1.groupby([ser1.dt.year, ser1.dt.month]).count()
sgp2 = ser2.groupby([ser2.dt.year, ser2.dt.month]).count()

df = pd.concat([sgp1, sgp2], axis=1).fillna(0)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(20, 10), sharex=True)

df[0].plot(kind='bar', ax=axes[0])
df[1].plot(kind='bar', ax=axes[1])
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]